# Like clause with Rails 3 and Sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, concatenation, sql-like

I have a `users` table with `name` and `surname` and a search form with only a `full_name` field. **How can I get it working?**

I tried with this simple code:

```
where_clause = "(name + ' ' + surname) LIKE ?"
# page is a will_paginate method
@users = User.where([where_clause, "%#{params[:full_name]}%"]).page params[:page]
```

The above code produces:

```
 SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ((name + ' ' + surname) LIKE '%test%') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

... which gives **no results**! **Why?**

I think the problem relies in the concatenation, but I can't see any alternatives. In fact I can't modify the select clause (i.e. "*, (name + ' ' + surname) AS full_name") because the page method doesn't work with active record find, and will_paginate methods (i.e. page or paginate) seems not to support conditions any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
where_clause = "(name || ' ' || surname) LIKE ?"
```